# Associative array not functioning properly

Tags: javascript

I have this code:

```
<?php 
if(mysqli_num_rows($result2) >= 2){
foreach($label_name as $meal_option_id => $names_of_labels)
{
    echo '<button price='.$protein_prices[$meal_option_id].' label_option= '.$meal_option_id.'  data-label-option= '.$meal_option_id.' class="view1 white cbtn1 open_sansbold option protein-option">' .$names_of_labels. ' <span id="price-difference-for-'.$meal_option_id.'"></span></button>';
}}?>
```

Javascript:

```
$(function() {
    var meal_qty = new Array(); 
    var label_options = new Array(); 
    var qty_options = new Array();

    $(".protein-option").click(function() {
        var meal_label_qty = $(this).data("label-option");
        // CREATE THE ASSOCIATIVE LABEL
        meal_qty[meal_label_qty] = [];
        // CREATE THE OBJECT WITH VALUES
        var item = {
            mon: $("#qty1").val(),
            tues: $("#qty2").val(),
            wed: $("#qty3").val(),
            thur: $("#qty4").val(),
            fri: $("#qty5").val()
        }
        // ADD TO ARRAY
        meal_qty[meal_label_qty] = item;

        console.log(meal_qty);
    });
});
```

Now item does contain the right values and so does `meal_label_qty` but my console log is:

```
(1003) [undefined × 1002, Object]
```

I wanted this output:

```
[meal_label_qty]
{
                mon: $("#qty1").val(),
                tues: $("#qty2").val(),
                wed: $("#qty3").val(),
                thur: $("#qty4").val(),
                fri: $("#qty5").val()  //WHICH IS ITEM
}
```

I realized my code goes the right meal_label_qty and item but starts writing Object after this code line `meal_qty[meal_label_qty] = [];`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaScript does not have associative arrays; it has zero-indexed arrays, and objects with properties. It might *seem* like there are associative arrays, since you can access a property from an object using similar syntax (`obj[property]`).

To get the output you desire, just change `meal_qty` to an object instead of an array, or, restructure your code a bit and push a new object into the array instead of assigning it to an index.

```
// add the quantity label to the item object
item.qty = meal_label_qty;

// push the whole object onto the array
meal_qty.push(item);
```

Comment: I did this 
`var meal_label_qty = $(this).data("label-option");
 
  // CREATE THE OBJECT WITH VALUES
  var item = {
   mon: $("#qty1").val(),
   tues: $("#qty2").val(),
   wed: $("#qty3").val(),
   thur: $("#qty4").val(),
   fri: $("#qty5").val()
  }

  item.qty = meal_label_qty;
  meal_qty.push(item);
  alert(meal_qty); ` i get [object] [Object]

Comment: The indexed array will always be a number "meal_label_qty" is always a number, so it should work

Comment: `alert` is just doing a toString on the meal_qty object, that's why you're seeing `[object Object]`. I'm a little unclear on what you are expecting to output when you log

Comment: Ok so I changed var meal_qty = {}; now I get Object `{1001: Object, 1002: Object}` Im guess that "object" is item, how can I fix this and make item show?

Comment: How to show them in your browser's console? Every browser does it a little differently. What are you using? If you console.log a single object, your dev tools should show you the properties/values inline.